# How can I implement CSRF protection with a ReactJs client and a remote NodeJs server cluster?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-services, csrf, websecurity

I'm having trouble trying to implement CSRF protections between a ReactJs client and a  remote NodeJs server cluster (no server sessions). I have a super simple project here (https://github.com/KevinAtMagenic/Example-CSRF-NodeJs/) that will replicate the problem. Clone it, then 'yarn i' and 'yarn dev' and you will be in the foxhole with me. A free lunch or beer and my eternal gratitude for anyone that can get this working, or at least point me in a better direction.

Thanks

- Kevin